# Wordpress - Filter search query to exclude postmeta value

Tags: wordpress, search, filter, posts

In my wordpress site I am making use of the `pre_get_posts` filter to customise my site search query. In functions file I have the following below.

Now my issue is, using FieldManager I have added a custom meta field called `hide_from_search_results` which is now included in my `wp_postmeta` table, with either a 0 or 1 Integer value. Not all posts/pages will have this field set however. I need to add the condition to not show anything that has this set to 1.

First I have joined the `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` tables like so:

```
function cf_search_join( $join ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( is_search() && !is_admin() ) {
        $join .=' LEFT JOIN '.$wpdb->postmeta. ' ON '. $wpdb->posts . '.ID = ' . $wpdb->postmeta . '.post_id ';
    }

    return $join;
}
add_filter('posts_join', 'cf_search_join' );
```

I then group the results by the post ID:

```
function cf_posts_groupby($groupby) {
    global $wpdb;

    if (is_search() && !is_admin()) {
        return $wpdb->posts . '.' . 'ID';
    }

    return $groupby;
}
add_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'cf_posts_groupby' );
```

Modify the search query with `posts_where` for things like excluding images from the results:

```
function cf_search_where( $where ) {
    global $pagenow, $wpdb;

    if ( is_search() && !is_admin() ) {
        $where = preg_replace(
            "/\(\s*".$wpdb->posts.".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
            "(".$wpdb->posts.".post_title LIKE $1) OR (".$wpdb->postmeta.".meta_value LIKE $1)", $where );
        
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_mime_type != "image/jpeg"';
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'cf_search_where' );
```

I lastly then use `pre_get_posts` to alter the query to include certain post types and only showing published:

```
function cf_posts_query( $query ) {
    if ( is_search() && !is_admin() ) {

        if (isset($_GET['post_types'])) {
            $query->set('post_type', $_GET['post_types']);
        } else {
            $query->set('post_type', ['page']);
        }

        $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'publish', 'inherit' ) );
      
    }

   return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'cf_posts_query' );
```

I have tried adding the following into my `cf_posts_query`

```
    $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
        array(
          'key' => 'hide_from_search_results',
          'compare' => '!=',
          'value' => 1
        )
      ));
```

But get the following error:

```
WordPress database error: [Not unique table/alias: 'wp_postmeta']
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (4440,4436) AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%coron%') OR (wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%coron%') OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%coron%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%coron%'))) AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'hide_from_search_results' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value != '1' ) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'inherit')) AND wp_posts.post_mime_type != "image/jpeg" GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%coron%' DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20

WordPress database error: [Not unique table/alias: 'wp_postmeta']
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_name IN ('search') AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (4440,4436) AND ( 0 = 1 ) AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'hide_from_search_results' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value != '1' ) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'inherit')) AND wp_posts.post_mime_type != "image/jpeg" GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Alternatively I have tried adding this whithin my `cf_search_where` function

```
$where .= ' AND (' . $wpdb->postmeta . '.meta_key != "hide_from_search_results") OR (' . $wpdb->postmeta . '.meta_key == "hide_from_search_results" AND ' . $wpdb->postmeta . '.meta_value == 1)';
```

But get:

```
WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== "hide_from_search_results" AND wp_postmeta.meta_value == "1") AND wp_posts.po' at line 1]
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (4440,4436) AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%coron%') OR (wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%coron%') OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%coron%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%coron%'))) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'inherit')) AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key != "hide_from_search_results") OR (wp_postmeta.meta_key == "hide_from_search_results" AND wp_postmeta.meta_value == "1") AND wp_posts.post_mime_type != "image/jpeg" GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%coron%' DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20

WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== "hide_from_search_results" AND wp_postmeta.meta_value == "1") AND wp_posts.po' at line 3]
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_name IN ('search') AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (4440,4436) AND ( 0 = 1 ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'inherit')) AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key != "hide_from_search_results") OR (wp_postmeta.meta_key == "hide_from_search_results" AND wp_postmeta.meta_value == "1") AND wp_posts.post_mime_type != "image/jpeg" GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to write your own `sql` statements and queries. I would avoid writing my own `sql` queries as much as possible because these custom `sql` queries would potentially make you vulnerable to `slq` attacks. In situations that you really have to write your own `sql` queries, then consider using `$wpdb->prepare`. However, i'd always use `wp_query` instead.

Also not sure whether you've stored your `meta_values` as an integer or string. I assume they're strings.

That being said, you could set up your `meta_query` in several ways:

For example, you could try this, if you had this value set for all of your `posts` and `pages`:

```php
$query->set( 'meta_query', array(
 array(
   'key' => 'hide_from_search_results',
   'value' => '0'
 )
));
```

Another solution you could try (This one would hopefully solve your issue):

```php
$query->set( 'meta_query', array(
 array(
   'key' => 'hide_from_search_results',
   'value'   => array( '1' ),
   'compare' => 'NOT IN'
 )
));
```

Honestly, your problem is hard to reproduce because of those custom `sql` queries, and your `meta_value` type is not clear whether it's an integer or string, therefore you may need to try different combinations of `meta_query`. If my answer didn't get you what you need, then the following link would be a good place to start trying different combinations of `meta_query`:

> [meta_query documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters)

---

**Update**
If your `meta_value` is an integer, then you would have to remove the "quotes" from your value.

```php
$query->set( 'meta_query', array(
 array(
   'key' => 'hide_from_search_results',
   'value'   => array( 1 ),
   'compare' => 'NOT IN'
 )
));
```

Or

```php
$query->set( 'meta_query', array(
 array(
   'key' => 'hide_from_search_results',
   'value'   => 1,
   'compare' => '!=',
   'type'=>'numeric'
 )
));
```

Comment: Thank you. The value is an integer (I have updated my original question). I have tried your code and it still either gives an error of `WordPress database error: [Not unique table/alias: 'wp_postmeta']` or if I add a table alias in my `cf_search_join` function it then returns no results at all (though no error is thrown)

Comment: Okay! Just updated my answer. Please give it a try!

Comment: Unfortunately that still has the same result where by the search either throws the table alias error or returns no results with a table alias.

Comment: These errors are to be expected. Like i said, custom `sql` queries would have the potential of opening up all sorts of nasty errors and vulnerabilities which make your code difficult to maintain in the long run which make your life harder. That being said, the error you mentioned in your comment is related to the table alias. So consider using `{$wpdb->prefix}postmeta` instead of using `wp_postmeta`. See if that would debug your code.